# Can you access application delegate from within a UITableViewDataSource function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to figure out the SQLite functionality for the iPhone, and I'm having some problems reading my database file from an overridden UITableViewDataSource function. I am storing the database file location in an ivar (as an NSString) in my application delegate, however when I try to access that string from an overridden UITableViewDataSource function, it returns some other object. If I access the string from any of the classes own instance methods, it works fine.

Is there any way to access the application delegate from within overridden UITableViewDataSource functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be really simple. I had created the NSString to hold the path to my database file using stringByAppendingPathComponent: . I failed to realize that this was going to be autoreleased, and so I didn't bother to explicitly retain it. That reason it was returning a different type of object was because that memory had been reused once the string had been autoreleased.

Explicitly retaining the string holding the path to the database file solved the problem.

Answer (score 75):

The Application is a singleton which maintains a reference to the app delegate. You can always access your app delegate using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

You may need to cast the return to your own app delegate class to get rid of warnings. Even better, write an accessor that returns your upcast app delegate:

```
#pragma mark access to app delegate etc.
+ (MyAppDelegateClass*) sharedAppDelegate; {
    return (MyAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Comment: Is the semicolon in `sharedAppDelegate;` a mistake?

Comment: Nope, it's valid Objective-C

Answer (score 22):

Roger is correct, but I personally find it extremely confusing to mix dot syntax and bracket syntax in the same statement.

If this confuses you as well, the equivalent syntax, using only bracket notation, is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and yes, you may need to cast the result to be *your* application delegate class, rather than the generic UIApplicationDelegate class, or you will get a number of compiler warnings, most likely.

Comment: No may about it. To make this useful, you WILL need to cast the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 8):

While I don't like sticking *too* much into my AppDelegate, I'll often need to access it to get to other singletons in my app, which makes the method call + cast a little cumbersome. So in most of my apps, I'll define a quick macro in my global header file.

Example follows:

```
#define MY_DELEGATE (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

It's a lot easier to refer to `MY_DELEGATE`.

Comment: That's pretty useful. But my eyes start to bleed when I see people prefixing things by "My". I can't imagine who else might own it…

Also, I'm not sure why you'd need `AppDelegate` to access singletons. A singleton is accessed like `[[MyHowdyClass sharedHowdyer] someMethod]`. No `AppDelegate` required.

Comment: (1) If it saves any face, I also despise "My" in identifiers. For the sake of illustration I wrote "MY" to replace my app's initials--mine actually reads "QM_DELEGATE". Your "MyHowdyClass" did this too ;)       (2) You're absolutely right that (design pattern) singletons should be accessed directly--I was over-simplifying; I should have said "shared instance" or something to denote a third-party class of which my entire app will make use of just a single instance. Not itself a singleton, but not always worth wrapping into one. Having it on the AppDelegate for easy access is handy in this case.

Comment: Haha… Got it. [extra text to get SO to let me leave a comment]

Comment: The preprocessing is not the best way to do this.

Comment: @RogerNolan Why is preprocessing not the best way to do this?  It is still doing the same exact thing, but just replacing the text.  And the preprocessor is only run through when compiling so therefore the user will not feel any performance difference.

Comment: @Flipper because the debugger* gets confused by preprocessed code. You can't inspect through the pre-processed code. It's much more difficult to read the code than a real method too. (* LLVM addresses this but there's no guarantee someone is using LLVM)