# NSManagedObjectContext, declared where?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Sorry for the newbness that follows. Your patience is greatly appreciated.

When adding a new object to core data, the correct initializer is this:

```
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:    (NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

Ok, so the initWithEntity part I understand. I only have one entity in my core data model, so I put it there. The context is where I'm confused. Firstly, where do declare the context, or do I even need to declare it? Simply typing self.ManagedObjectContext doesn't work, nor does it autocomplete. Perhaps because I'm trying to call this method from my AddViewController is the reason, so even if I type Car.ManagedObjectContext or AppDelegate.ManagedObjectContext the same thing happens. I'm guessing I could declare it in my care-data generated model class (Car.h) but what does it actually do?

What am I not understanding here? Sorry for the newb question. I've really been trying to figure this out for hours.

Here's my code.

car.h:

```
@interface Car : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * brand;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * model;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * year;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * engineSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * weight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id image;

@end

car.m:

#import "Car.h"


@implementation Car

@dynamic brand;
@dynamic model;
@dynamic year;
@dynamic color;
@dynamic engineSize;
@dynamic weight;
@dynamic image;

@end
```

addViewController.h (didn't include AppDelegate since it's all pretty much standard and seems to work fine. All the coding I did was in the addview controller):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AddViewController : NSWindowController{
  }

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *brandField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *modelField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *yearField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *weightField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *engineSizeField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *colorField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSImageView *imageField;


- (IBAction)saveCar:(id)sender;

@end

AddViewController.m:


#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Car.h"
@interface AddViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddViewController
@synthesize brandField;
@synthesize modelField;
@synthesize yearField;
@synthesize engineSizeField;
@synthesize weightField;
@synthesize colorField;
@synthesize imageField;



- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

- (IBAction)saveCar:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Car managedObjectContext]; //This doesn't work here   "no known class method"


    Car *newCar = [[Car alloc] initWithEntity:@"Car" insertIntoManagedObjectContext:Car.managedObjectContext]; //compiler complains about this, property not found.


    newCar.brand = [brandField stringValue];
    newCar.model =  [modelField stringValue];
    newCar.year =  [yearField stringValue];
    newCar.weight = [weightField objectValue];
    newCar.engineSize = [engineSizeField objectValue];
    newCar.color = [colorField stringValue];
    newCar.image = imageField;


}


@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a managedObjectContext. 
It is typically done in the appDelegate.
Apples has a good article about it: [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html)

Comment: Thank you! I've looked through tons of Apple documentation but I must've glossed over this. I'm only confused about one thing though. I can see where the managedObjectContext method is declared in AppDelegate, however where do I call this method from? I tried putting it in the AddViewController as the first line in my saveCar method as NSManagedObjectContext *context = [AppDelegate managedObjectContext]; but I'm getting a "no known class method" error from the compiler.

Comment: You can get in hold of the app delegate like this: (MyAppDelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817259/can-you-access-application-delegate-from-within-a-uitableviewdatasource-function)