# how to pass CoreLocation values from one VIewController to AppDelegate in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-location

I am able to obtain latitude and longitude values in one ViewController .Now i want to pass these values to AppDelegate where i can use them.I don't want to use Core Location in AppDelegate..so that approach is not of use.How can i achieve his?

Here is my Appdelegate code -

```
-(void)updatePresence
{
 NSString *string = self.userLocationVC.locationInfo;// lat and long values as string.
 NSLog(@"value of string in appDelegate - %@", string);  // This shows null.
}
```

'userLocationVC' is my ViewController where i calculate location values and 'locationInfo' is NSString property of that controller where i store the obtained values.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
  {
   NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
   CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

  if (currentLocation != nil)
  {
    longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    self.locationInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude - %@ , longitude - %@",latitude,longitude];
    NSLog(@"current location is - %@", locationInfo);
    AppDelegate *myappDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [myappDelegate updatePresence];
```

Comment: why not "[myappDelegate updatePresence:self.locationInfo];"?

Comment: if i do that i get an error saying - No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate'declares the selector 'updatePresence'.

Comment: why don't you want to declare it?

Comment: I was told to implement in that way :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use notifications, where you send a notification from the view controller and it is observed by your app delegate. Pass the location string along with the notification.

This has the advantage that if you later decide to move the location data to another model class, then you just need to add an observer there, and stop observing in the app delegate.

If the reason you want to do this is to make use of the background/foreground delegate methods in the app delegate, then consider using the notification equivalents of these in your view controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the most simple solution would be to have add an instance variable to your Application Delegate, then in your location ViewController get a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817259/can-you-access-application-delegate-from-within-a-uitableviewdatasource-function) to your Application Delegate and set the ivar retrospectively.

However I think it's bad practice to use the app delegate in this fashion.

I have only once added an instance variable to the app delegate and that was to store a device ID, when I was implementing push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Create a LocationManager singleton class to retrieve your location and call it whenever you need

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

static NSString * const LocationManagerDidGetFirstAccurateLocationNotification = @"LocationManagerDidGetFirstAccurateLocationNotification";

@interface LocationManager : CLLocationManager <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (readonly, nonatomic) CLPlacemark * currentPlacemark;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) CLLocation  * currentLocation;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber    * latitude;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber    * longitude;

+ (LocationManager *)sharedManager;
- (void)start;

- (double)currentDistanceFromLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude
                            longitude:(NSNumber *)longitude;

@end




//
//  LocationManager.m
//  Post
//
//  Created by Nicolas Manzini on 26.01.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 MySo. All rights reserved.
//

#import "LocationManager.h"

@interface LocationManager ()

@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isWaitingFirstLocation) BOOL waitingFirstLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer * timer;
@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isStarted) BOOL started;

- (void)restartLocationUpdates:(NSTimer *)timer;
- (void)addObservers;
- (void)addTimer;
- (void)updatePlacemarkFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location;

@end

@implementation LocationManager

@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

+ (LocationManager *)sharedManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static LocationManager * sharedManager = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)start
{
    if (self.isStarted) {return;}

    _currentLocation          = nil;
    self.desiredAccuracy      = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.distanceFilter       = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.delegate             = self;
    self.started              = YES;
    self.waitingFirstLocation = YES;

    [self startUpdatingLocation];
    [self addObservers];
    [self addTimer];
}

- (void)addObservers
{
    NSNotificationCenter * center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
    {
        [self stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self.timer invalidate];
         self.timer = nil;

        _currentPlacemark = nil;
        _currentLocation  = nil;
    }];

    [center addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
    {
        self.waitingFirstLocation = YES;
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        [self addTimer];
    }];
}

- (void)addTimer
{
    self.timer =
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(restartLocationUpdates:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

#pragma mark - delegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation * location = [locations lastObject];
    _currentLocation      = location;

    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 30.0)
    {
        [self stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self updatePlacemarkFromLocation:location];
    }
    else if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 100.0 && self.isWaitingFirstLocation)
    {
        self.waitingFirstLocation = NO;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:LocationManagerDidGetFirstAccurateLocationNotification
                                                            object:nil];
        [self updatePlacemarkFromLocation:location];

    }
}

#pragma mark - timer

- (void)restartLocationUpdates:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - NSNumber Coordinates

- (NSNumber *)latitude
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}

- (NSNumber *)longitude
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}

#pragma mark - Distance From location

- (double)currentDistanceFromLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude
                            longitude:(NSNumber *)longitude
{
    CLLocation * distantLocation =
    [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude doubleValue]
                               longitude:[longitude doubleValue]];
    double meters =
    [self.currentLocation distanceFromLocation:distantLocation];

    return meters;
}

#pragma mark - Placemark Lookup

- (void)updatePlacemarkFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                                    completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"could not get current geolocation infos %@",error);
         }
         _currentPlacemark = [placemark firstObject];
     }];
}

#pragma mark - dealloc

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: here's my class you can copy past